# Automation : Move files from source folder to destination folder one by one and delete the file from source folder

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

Scenario :

I have 2 files in the DOWNLOAD folder.
1. A.csv 
2. B.csv

A.csv gets downloaded first and then B.csv gets downloaded.

I want to move A.csv to Folder1 and as soon as the file is moved, A.csv should get deleted from download folder and then B.csv file should get downloaded and it should be moved to Folder2 and as soon as the file is moved, B.csv should get deleted from download folder.

My Code :

I am getting "The method copyDirectory(File, File, boolean) in the type FileUtils is not applicable for the arguments (File, File, new FileFilter(){})" error in the FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, dest, new FileFilter() line. My code is as follows:

```
List<WebElement> list= wd.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='lcb']/tbody/tr/td/table[@class='ibody']/tbody/tr/td[contains(translate(text(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'csv')]/parent::tr/td[7]/a"));
for (WebElement element:list)
{

 element.click();
 ++count;
 if(count==1)
 {
try{
 File source = new File("C:\\Users\\sh370472\\Downloads");
  File dest = new File("E:\\PAS\\");

      FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, dest, new FileFilter() {

          @Override
          public boolean accept(File pathname) 
          {
            boolean source=pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv");
              if (source)
              {

                pathname.deleteOnExit();
                  return true;
              }
                  return false;

             } 

      });
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
 Thread.sleep(9000);
 if(count==2)
 {
     File source1 = new File("C:\\Users\\sh370472\\Downloads");
        File dest1 = new File("E:\\TAS\\");

            FileUtils.copyDirectory(source1, dest1, new FileFilter() {

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File pathname) 
                {
                    boolean source1=pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv");
                    if (source1)
                    {

                        pathname.deleteOnExit();
                        return true;
                    }
                        return false;

                   }

            });

        } 
}
```

Can somebody tell me how to rectify this error or suggest any alternative

Answer (score 0):

FileUtils isn't a standard java utility class, but from your error message copyDirectory takes a Boolean as the last parameter, not a filter.  You should figure out if there is another method that takes the filter.

Even with that solved, I don't ever see where you download a file.  You are copying from source to dest but both of those are directories--neither is an FTP site.

You need to start by downloading a list of files from your FTP site then you can loop over that list and download/copy/delete each one.

You never use your WebElement parameter--is that where your file list is coming from?

Comment: I am downloading the file using element.click()

Comment: yes the first file is coming from WebElement parameter.

Comment: Could you please suggest me an alternative to move files. It's really very urgent.

Comment: To copy the file, try this: Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());  Then to delete it try source.delete();  How you download it from the ftp site depends on which tools you are using.